# In vue, how to not allow mouseover to affect every element of the list?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, hover, mouseover, v-for

I have a v-for, every element of the list has a mouseover event. I would like that when mouseover on that element, a variable value is changed and so a div appears next to that element(.checkbox div). But instead, since all elements use the same variable all divs appear. Here's my code:

```
<md-card v-for="route in routes" :key="route.id">
    <md-card-area>
      <div class="checkbox" v-show="hover == true" @mouseover="hover = true">
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="route.checked"/>
      </div>
      <div @mouseover="hover = true" @mouseout="function() { if (route.checked == false) hover = false }">
       </div>
    </md card-area>
</md-card>
```

I have tried to use mouseover.native but it won't work. I have also tried using instead of changing hover variable, changing route.hover variable but it won't be changed.

Comment: Why not add the `hover` variable to each route object in `routes`? that way you can use `@mouseover="route.hover = true"` instead

Comment: As I said in my question: "I have also tried using instead of changing hover variable, changing route.hover variable but it won't be changed."

Comment: The routes should define the prop `hover` before using it.

Comment: It adds the property correctly, problem is the value doesn't change.

Comment: you should use `$set` method in order to make that reactive, `route.hover=true;$set(routes,index,route)` don't forget to add `index` in `v-for="(route,index) in routes" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another variable called `currentIndex` :

```
data(){
  return{
    currentIndex:-1,
     hover:false,

  }
}
```

add `index` in v-for loop and update the `currentIndex` with the hovered index and add this condition `hover == true && currentIndex===index`:

```
<md-card v-for="(route,index) in routes" :key="route.id">
    <md-card-area>
      <div class="checkbox" v-show="hover == true && currentIndex===index" @mouseover="hover = true" >
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="route.checked"/>
      </div>
      <div @mouseover="hover = true;currentIndex=index" @mouseout="function() { if (route.checked == false){ hover = false; currentIndex=-1;} }">
       </div>
    </md card-area>
</md-card>
```